# How to return the frustum of the THREE.Perspective camera and store it as a variable?

Tags: three.js, camera, frustum

I was looking on Three.js API and I found that the [Frustum](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum) is used for the camera visible area. I was wondering if I can access the view frustum of my [PerspectiveCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera) and declare the frustum as an object. Basically, my goal is to color the frustum of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to visualize the frustum of your camera, you can use a `THREE.CameraHelper`. It essentially does what you're describing in the question: it lets you color the frustum so you can visualize it.

To implement it, you simply need to initiate it with your camera as a parameter, then add it to the scene:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, camRatio, 0.1, 1000 );
var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( camera );
scene.add( helper );
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper) and you can see it in action [on the right side of this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera)

#### Update:

If you want to read the data used to build the helper, you can access its [`.pointmap`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper.pointMap) property. It's got lots of points that determine the position of the near plane (`n1, n2, n3...`), far plane (`f1, f2, f3...`), target, etc. To get better acquainted with what each key means, you can [look at its constructor](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/CameraHelper.js) from line 38 to 83. The code is very well-documented in there.

Comment: As shown in the figure I already have it. the problem is that i dont know what the values of it (near plane positions, far plane positions, distance, ...etc)

Comment: Ah, my mistake! Bad answer. I thought you were asking how to visualize the frustum as demonstrated in the screenshot.

Comment: Great this works and returns pointmap will return `{n1: Array(4), n2: Array(4), n4: Array(4), n3: Array(4), f1: Array(3), …}`. However, can I return the geometry of that array or do I have to create it myself (e.g THREE.BoxGeometry)??

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to access its geometry with `helper.geometry`. You could also change its material with `helper.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` or whatever else you want.

Comment: Just created another question in more detail about this. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808325/accessing-perspectivecamera-geometry-to-generate-rays-inside-its-buffergeometry)

Comment: the answer does not show code that returns the frustrum of the camera, it just shows how to add the camera helper